# How to subscribe to StateFlow in kotlin-react useEffect

Tags: kotlin, react-hooks, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to create a small counter example for kotlin-react with `functionalComponent` with kotlin `1.4-M2`.
The example should use `kotlinx.coroutines.flow`. I'm struggling at collecting the values from the store in reacts `useEffect` hook.

Store:

```kotlin
object CounterModel { // Modified sample from kotlin StateFlow doc
    private val _counter = MutableStateFlow(0) // private mutable state flow
    val counter: StateFlow<Int> get() = _counter // publicly exposed as read-only state flow

    fun inc() { _counter.value++ }
}
```

Component:

```kotlin
val counter = functionalComponent<RProps> {
    val (counterState, setCounter) = useState(CounterModel.counter.value)

    useEffect(listOf()) {
        // This does not work
        GlobalScope.launch { CounterModel.counter.collect { setCounter(it) } }
    }
    
    div {
        h1 {
            +"Counter: $counterState"
        }
        button {
            attrs.onClickFunction = { CounterModel.inc() }
        }
    }
}
```

When I directly call `CounterModel.counter.collect { setCounter(it) }` it complains about `Suspend function 'collect' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`.

How would you implement this `useEffect` hook?

And once the subscription works, how would you unsubscribe from it (use `useEffectWithCleanup` instead of `useEffect`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution. We can use `onEach` to do an action for every new value and then 'subscribe' with `launchIn`. This returns a job that can be canceled for cleanup:

```kotlin
object CounterStore {
    private val _counter = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val counter: StateFlow<Int> get() = _counter
    
    fun inc() { _counter.value++ }
}

val welcome = functionalComponent<RProps> {
    val (counter, setCounter) = useState(CounterStore.counter.value)

    useEffectWithCleanup(listOf()) {
        val job = CounterStore.counter.onEach { setCounter(it) }.launchIn(GlobalScope)
        return@useEffectWithCleanup { job.cancel() }
    }

    div {
        +"Counter: $counter"
    }
    button {
        attrs.onClickFunction = { CounterStore.inc() }
        +"Increment"
    }
}
```

We can extract this StateFlow logic to a custom react hook:

```kotlin
fun <T> useStateFlow(flow: StateFlow<T>): T {
    val (state, setState) = useState(flow.value)

    useEffectWithCleanup(listOf()) {
        val job = flow.onEach { setState(it) }.launchIn(GlobalScope)
        return@useEffectWithCleanup { job.cancel() }
    }
    
    return state
}
```

And use it like this in our component:

```kotlin
val counter = useStateFlow(CounterStore.counter)
```

The complete project can be found [here](https://github.com/piu130/flow-counter).
The Flow-Api is very experimental so this might not be the final solution :)

Answer (score 0):

if's very important to check that the value hasn't changed,
before calling `setState`, otherwise the rendering happens twice

```
external interface ViewModelProps : RProps {
    var viewModel : MyViewModel
}
val App = functionalComponent<ViewModelProps> { props ->
    val model = props.viewModel
    val (state, setState) = useState(model.stateFlow.value)
    useEffectWithCleanup {
        val job = model.stateFlow.onEach {
            if (it != state) {
                setState(it)
            }
        }.launchIn(GlobalScope)
        return@useEffectWithCleanup { job.cancel() }
    }
}
```

Comment: `StateFlow` should do that for you. It only triggers changes when the `newState != oldState`. Otherwise you could use `Flow<T>.distinctUntilChanged()`.

Comment: I verified that without such condition, the rendering happens twice.
`StateFlow` is already implementing `distinctUntilChanged()`.

Comment: `StateFow` immediately emits the initial value. A simple `drop(1)` should do.